# df.iloc Not Assigning Values in a For-loop? (pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly new to pandas, I have a dataset containing about 250,000 rows, stored in a JSON. One of my columns contains a long, possibly unique string in each cell which I have to filter some before the data is usable. For some reason, each value is being accessed and filtered correctly (meaning the correct value is stored in my processing variable at the end), but when it comes to assignment with df.iloc[x]['notes'], the values are not correctly reassigned into the dataframe. I've read about issues with chained indexing and assignment in pandas, but I thought that this would be circumvented by using .iloc, and it just isn't working for me right now.

Here's an example:

Assume this is my dataframe and some filtering code:

```
import pandas as pd 

#Listing the things I want to filter out
greeting = ['Hello,', 'Hi']
goodbye = ['Thank you', 'Goodbye']

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[123, 456, 789], 'Group':['A', 'B', 'C'],\
'notes':['Hello, this is John', 'Thank you for your help',\
'This is a message.']})

#Doing the actual filtering
for x in range(0, len(df['notes'])):

    note = df.iloc[x]['notes']

    for y in greeting:
        if y in note:
            note = note.replace(y, '')

    for z in goodbye:
        if z in note:
            note = note.replace(z, '')

#The variable note is correctly filtered here,\
but then it doesn't assign and leaves the df unchanged\
at the previous index, so error is probably beyond this point

    df.iloc[x]['notes'] = note
df.to_json('final_data.json', orient = 'records')
```

Another thing I've used in place of .iloc is df.at[x, 'notes'] = note, but this seems to have the same problem.

So in the final version, instead of getting something like:

[{'ID':1, 'Group': "A", 'notes':' this is John'}..etc.]

I get:

[{'ID':1, 'Group': "A", 'notes':'Hello, this is John'}..etc.]
(which is completely unchanged)

What is happening here? Is there some unpredictable assignment going on that I can somehow fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
df['notes'] = df['notes'].str.replace('|'.join(greeting + goodbye), '')
```

And now:

```
df.to_json('final_data.json', orient = 'records')
```

Will give you a good desired `json` file.

As:

```
[{"Group":"A","ID":123,"notes":" this is John"},{"Group":"B","ID":456,"notes":" for your help"},{"Group":"C","ID":789,"notes":"This is a message."}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! Do you have any idea why iloc didn't work in the first place?

Comment: @Bonnie because you assigned it to a variable and it has no more relation to the dataframe :D, happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below.

Var `idx` is the index of the dataframe `df`, you can pass `idx` to .loc() to index. Var `row` is a series, which contain data in a single row.

```py
for idx, row in df.iterrows():

    note = row['notes']

    for y in greeting:
        if y in note:
            note = note.replace(y, '')

    for z in goodbye:
        if z in note:
            note = note.replace(z, '')

    df.loc[idx, 'notes'] = note
```